# Add Live Support section to mvc 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Greeting to the community. This is my very first question.

I had in mind to add [Livezilla](http://www.livezilla.net) live support in my MVC website, but I realised that there are some problems.

First of all, it is written in php and mysql, so is it possible to comply with MVC and sql server?

Does anybody know a similar solution (like livezilla) in my case?

PS. Excuse my poor english...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just uploaded the folder given from livezilla in the root folder of my website. Then the only need to met is to have a Mysql server to create the database for livezilla. After that php and mvc runs together with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could even look into using an iFrame to run livezilla inside of an mvc3 page if you wanted.

or, you could roll your own. if you wanted to try implementing a live response mvc3 page look into jquery and ajax asynchronous calls such as $.post and also look into the extension for controller AsyncController, and [AsyncTimeout(XXX)]. you will also have to read up on sending and receiving json objects in ajax and from a controller to the view.

Simple psuedo:

View:

setTimeOut calls a javascript function every X milliseconds

the javascript function uses json to wrap page data and pass it to the controller inside a $.post() call

Controller:

recieves page data as an model object in a post

determines if page is out of sync or not

returns relevant sync data in a json object back to the view

View:

the same javascript function receives the json object from controller

updates the page based on relevant sync data